# How can i resample "roc_curve" (fpr,tpr )?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm looking to resample "roc_curve" (sklearn) output.

When i plot fpr,tpr  in Ipython it is fine, but sometimes i want to export it (mostly for client), but it's hard to understand because it's not linear.

For example

```
fpr =[0,0.1,0.4,0.9,1]
tpr =[0,0.3,0.4,0.5,1]
```

How can i resample `fpr` to be linear every 5% ex :

```
[0,0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2,0.25,0.3,0.35,0.4,0.45,0.5,0.55,0.6,0.65,0.7,0.75,0.,0.85,0.9,0.95,1]
```

and `tpr` :

```
[0,0.15,0.3,0.3167,0.333,0.35,0.3667,0.383,0.4,0.41,0.42,0.43,0.44,0.45,0.46,0.47,0.48,0.49,0.5,0.75,1]
```

How can i proceed ?

Comment: What exactly should be the output? I don't really get what `resampling` means in your context.

Comment: i have edited the question for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is piecewise constant interpolation.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import spline

fpr =[0,0.1,0.4,0.9,1]
tpr =[0,0.3,0.4,0.5,1]

n = 20
x_interp = np.linspace(0,1,n+1)
y_interp = spline(fpr, tpr, x_interp, order=0)
```

`x_interp` are the `fpr` values

```
[ 0.    0.05  0.1   0.15  0.2   0.25  0.3   0.35  0.4   0.45  0.5   0.55
  0.6   0.65  0.7   0.75  0.8   0.85  0.9   0.95  1.  ]
```

`y_interp` are the corresponding `tpr` values

```
[ 0.   0.   0.3  0.3  0.3  0.3  0.3  0.3  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4
  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.5  0.5  0.5]
```

Comment: @steboc, I thought about that too, but I am not sure if that's a good idea. The problem I see here is that this would smooth the roc curve and I find it hard to justify why this makes sense.

Comment: can't find spline on scipy doc. is there a new name ?

Comment: It's actually a wrapper function: The code is here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/a1e831382e1f58c791a32eab95f442e4f25b09cd/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py#L2328-2351.